# Prove that the distance between the intersection point of these 2 functions and the origin is less then 2

Tags: calculus

I have two functions, $f(x)= x^2+x+1$ and $g(x)= \frac{1}{x}$. I have to prove that their point of intersection has a distance from the origin $<2$.

This is a high school problem so the proof shouldn't use more then derivatives. 
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Comment: I would recommend writing your thoughts on this problem and telling is where you encounter a problem. Just stating a problem makes it like you're a teacher and we're students solving problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, lets find the point of intersection by equating the two functions:

$x^{2} + x+1 = \frac{1}{x}$

$x^{3} + x^{2} + x -1=0$

By considering the graph of this function, we see that it has $1$ real root. Calculating this root is possible, but not necessary. Instead we must find the interval in which this root exists by looking at sign changes.

Let $h(x) = x^{3} + x^{2} + x -1$

$h(1) > 0$, $h(\frac{1}{2})<0$

Lets call the real root $\alpha$, then we have $\frac{1}{2} < \alpha < 1$

Now the $y$ coordinate of the point of intersection is at $g(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\alpha}$

So the point of intersection is at $(\alpha, \frac{1}{\alpha})$

The distance, $D$, from the origin to this point is given by Pythagoras:

$D(\alpha) = \sqrt{\alpha ^{2} + \frac{1}{\alpha ^{2}}}$

$\frac{dD}{d\alpha} = 2\alpha - \frac{2}{\alpha ^{3}} = \frac{2(\alpha ^{4} - 1)}{\alpha ^{3}} < 0$ for $\frac{1}{2} < \alpha < 1$

Therefore $D$ is strictly decreasing in this domain.

Consider what value of $c$ would give $D(c) = 2$:

We find that $c$ = $\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}$

Now we check the sign of $h(c)$:

$h(c) = (2-\sqrt{3})^{\frac{3}{2}} + 2 - \sqrt{3} + (2-\sqrt{3})^{\frac{1}{2}} -1$

$h(c) = (2-\sqrt{3})^{\frac{1}{2}}(3-\sqrt{3}) + 1-\sqrt{3}$

$h(c) = \sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}-1)(2-\sqrt{3})^{\frac{1}{2}} + 1-\sqrt{3}$

$h(c) = (\sqrt{3} -1)(\sqrt{3}(2-\sqrt{3})^{\frac{1}{2}} -1)$

Now to prove that $h(c) < 0$, we must prove that:

$\sqrt{3}(2-\sqrt{3})^{\frac{1}{2}} < 1$

Since both sides are positive we can do the following:

$\Leftrightarrow 1 > 3(2-\sqrt{3}) \Leftrightarrow 3\sqrt{3} > 5 \Leftrightarrow 27 > 25$ which is true, hence the initial statement is also true since every step was an if and only if statement.

$\Rightarrow h(c) < 0$ which means $c$ is our new lower-bound for $\alpha$
$ \Rightarrow c<\alpha < 1$

Since $D$ is strictly decreasing, we have that the maximum value of $D$ would occur at the smallest value of $\alpha$(the value of $\alpha$ is of course fixed, we are just considering the limiting case given our constraints on $\alpha$). Since we found $c$ by setting $D(c) = 2$, and $c<\alpha < 1$, it follows that $D<2$.

Comment: Ok with the beginning of your proof, but with the last part : $\alpha$ is not a variable that you may choose ! Instead, as you mentioned, it is a constant value, somewhere between $1/2$ and $1$ ...

Comment: It is simply taking the limiting case, that is to say suppose $\alpha$ were $1$, then this would give the largest value of $D$ for any $\alpha$ in this range. This value of $D$ is $\sqrt{2}$ . It then follows that $D < \sqrt{2}$

Comment: `Clearly D takes it's maximum value when α takes its maximum value` Why? $D(\frac{1}{2}) \gt D(1)\,$. In fact $\alpha=1$ gives the *minimum* value for $D$ (by AM-GM).

Comment: $\alpha^2+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$ is always greater than $2$, hence $D$ cannot be $<\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I have made a mistake, working on a fix

Comment: Wow that was much harder than I thought it would be. Do you guys agree with it now?

Comment: @mrnovice Looks good to me now. Could also use $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})$ at the last steps, but I don't know that it simplifies things much.

Comment: Yeah I mean of course your method is far more efficient, but it's still a different and valid approach

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to find the roots of a third degree polynomial to prove your inequality.

The given parabola and hyperbola intesect at a point whose abscissa $x\in(0,1)$. Its squared distance from the origin is given by $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$, that is a number greater than $2$. We have to prove it is less than $4$. That is the same as proving that $x^2> 2-\sqrt{3}$. Since $g(x)=x^2+x+1-\frac{1}{x}$ is an increasing function on $[0,\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}]$, it is enough to check that $g(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}})<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the point of intersection satisfies $P(x)=x^{3} + x^{2} + x -1=0\,$, so for that point:

$$x^3 = -x^2-x+1 \tag{1}$$

The distance to the origin is $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}\,$. Squaring, eliminating denominators, and using $(1)$ to eliminate powers of $x$ higher than $2$ gives:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
r^2 x^2 & = x^4+1 \\
 & = x(-x^2-x+1) + 1 \\
 & = -x^3 -x^2 +x +1 \\
 & = -(\cancel{-x^2}-x+\bcancel{1}) -\cancel{x^2} + x + \bcancel{1} \\
 & = 2 x
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $r^2 = \cfrac{2}{x}\,$, so all that's left to prove is that $x \gt \cfrac{1}{2}\,$ which follows from $P\left(\cfrac{1}{2}\right)\cdot P(1) \lt 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Equate the two equations and then prove that the $x$ coordinate of the intersection point is in the interval $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. This should be enough find bounds of $y$ and then we can use the Distance Formula to prove that the distance is less than $2$.

Comment: I couldn't find the point

Comment: you must solve the equation $$x^2+x+1=\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: @yoloexpectz Finding the point might not be easy, but I give you updated my hint and hopefully this will lead you to the answer.